# Consistency vs. Asymptotic Efficiency of estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, estimators

I'm thinking about the relationship between an asymptotically efficient estimator and a consistent estimator, and I'd like to make sure that my thinking is correct.

An estimator is asymptotically efficient if it is asymptotically unbiased and its asymptotic variance achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound, while an estimator is consistent if it converges in probability to the true parameter.

I'm particularly interested if one causes the other, and my thinking is as follows:

If an estimator is consistent, then it converges in probability to the true parameter. However, nothing is specified about the "rate of convergence", i.e. the asymptotic variance. On the other hand, an asymptotically efficient estimator not only converges in probability to the true parameter, but also does so at the fastest possible rate, i.e. with the smallest possible asymptotic variance for an asymptotically unbiased estimator.

Hence, it would be true that an asymptotically efficient estimator is consistent, but the converse may not be true.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is probably correct, assuming that some consistent estimator does exist! If none exists, it might be wrong.